setxkbmap multi layout and toggle not working
I installed regolith (based on i3 wm) on my Ubuntu 22.4, and now the default Keybind Super+Space to switch source layouts is not working because regolith uses it as a shortcut for other things.
I searched their Github repo and I found some answers but they don't work for me also other answers on the Internet like:

setxkbmap -model pc86 -layout us,ir -option 'grp:alt_shift_toggle'
localectl set-x11-keymap us,ir pc86
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt><Super>BackSpace']" 
Set keybind from GUI

Output of setxkbmap -query  :
rules:      evdev
model:      pc86
layout:     us,ru
options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp:alt_shift_space_toggle

But when I run setxkbmap -model pc86 -layout ir it works but only for Chrome, and when I added other langs to this command it did not work.
edit:
when I logout and logged to gnome desktop the keybinding by below command worked and I was able to switch between layouts but when I logged to regolith did not:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt><Super>BackSpace']"

I solved this issue which seems to be related to Wayland, by installing the X11 version of Regolith.
after a logout login to X11, and running this command to set new keybinding :
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt><Super>BackSpace']"
it worked.
